# How to say "that can be arranged"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, idiom

The phrase "that can be arranged" can be useful, and I would like to know an idiomatic way to put it in Latin.
This phrase could be a response to "can we meet tomorrow at ten?", "I'd like to eat something Italian tonight", "I need a receipt to be reimbursed", or many other things.

What would be a good Latin phrase for "that can be arranged"?
My instinct is to say *fieri potest* or *curari potest*, but there might be a more idiomatic way that I'm missing.

Comment: If your opinion carries weight "Fiat." 'let it be so.'

Answer (score 3):

I'd say that *fieri potest* or *curari potest*, while grammatically correct, lack the implication of approval that "that can be arranged" contains. Honestly, I'd go with *quidni?*—that is, "why not?"

Comment: Good point. I'm not sure if there's a way to say both "it's possible" and "I approve" in a couple of words in Latin, so I may have to choose which side to emphasize.

Comment: *Quidni* lacks any sense of authority on the part of the granter, though.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer OMG! I want to say "welcome back" but I'm worried it would jinx it. You're right about *quidni*. I suspect that Latin, being a deeply concrete language, simply doesn't have a way to get all the nuances of the original in one straightforward phrase or sentence.

Comment: Well, now look who's gone...